# Hide Android launcher icon

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am developing a android application, I want to hide launcher icon if application found other package com.example, else do nothing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

It will not disappear until the next reboot.